# selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\tamilarasua\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.indianmountain.org/reportofgiving/")
donor = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="elementor-tab-content-2391"]//ul//li')
print(donor)
time.sleep(3)
```

**<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="61f202f48187b7b3c0e52006c6e3a47a", element="4A359ACCB01296AC5B69FC86F23FA497_element_34")>**

it's showing the pop up. Any idea to solve this?

I'm trying to print the list in the elements

Comment: My guess is that you try to find element which is not loaded fast enough after you open url. Try using Selenium Waits: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get that information:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t 
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://www.indianmountain.org/reportofgiving/'
browser.get(url) 

elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="elementor-tab-content-2391"]//ul//li')))
for e in elements: 
    print(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Result in terminal:

```
Anonymous
Keith ’70 and Shirley Campbell
Richen Cong and Haixia Zhang P’20
Leonard Fong ’93 and Amy Chan P’22
Louis and Kathleen Hager P’21
Robert and Lisa Huffines P’19
Yoonsoo Huh and Alexis Lee P’21
Ching Lau Hui and Meiyun Wu P’20
Jun Hur* and Jiyeun Park P’20
Weizhu Jin and Jin Xue P’22
Jaeyoul Kim and Seohyun Lee P’19
Yuhoon and Eunok Kim P’20
Honggui and Yuxia Li P’20
Juhyun Lim and Sangjun Kim P’22
Esther Ma* and Chi Chung Lee P’22
Nicholas Moore P’85,’98,’03
Samuel and Ellen Posey P’97,’01
Xiaofeng Shen and Yilun Huang P’18
Mark and Monica Winmill P’28
MingJie Yi and Xiaohue He P’20,’22
Xiliang Zhang* and Yi Fang P’21
Dingping Zhu and Lin Gao P’20
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).